# Matching a certain word that is not surrounded by quotationmarks with regex

Tags: regex, pcre

At first I thought it would be very trivial to do this with regex, but it turns out, I'm wrong.

I can't seem to find a simple and reliable way of doing this with regex, so I'm putting it out there:

I want to match every instance of FOO that is not surrounded by quotations i.e:

FOO

xFOO

FOOy

"FOO

FOO"

but not "FOO"

In other words, I want to find FOO, but only if it's not in quotes.
I hope this makes sense. :-)

Comment: What about `"xFOOy"`? Should it be found?

Comment: Yes, everything containing FOO except when FOO has quotes on both sides, i.e. "FOO" should be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use lookarounds in your regex:

```
(?:(?<!")FOO|FOO(?!"))

$s = 'FOO"';
if (preg_match('/(?:(?<!")FOO|FOO(?!"))/', $s, $m))
    print_r($m);
```

This will match `FOO` it is not followed by `"` OR match FOO if it not preceded by `"`

In other words it will NOT match FOO only when FOO is enclosed in double quotes.

#### LIVE DEMO: http://ideone.com/kL3I3M

Comment: That is not what I want.
I want to match any instance of FOO that does not have a preceding AND a following " (both must be true)

Your example doesn't match "FOO

Comment: @Niklas: Test it out. It does exactly that i.e. match `FOO` when NOT enclosed by `"` on both sides.

Comment: **`LIVE DEMO:`** http://ideone.com/kL3I3M

Comment: I'm curious what the atomic group is for.

Comment: (?>(?<!")FOO|FOO(?!"))

![Regular expression visualization](https://www.debuggex.com/i/vqxHwWcXSJEvNEVe.png)

Comment: @Niklas: Look at the working PHP demo and then prove how it doesn't work. Those pictures on Debuggex won't tell you anything.

Comment: @KendallFrey: I just used to avoid back tracking once LHS of regex is true but I guess I could have used `(?:...)` also.

Comment: Once a regex is matched, there is no more backtracking.

Comment: @KendallFrey: Yes agreed, I updated to non matching group `(?:..)`

Comment: Even that isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: Yes agreed not required but why capture a text when its not needed.

Comment: @anubhava: I will eat my words and deem debuggex, well, bugged.

Comment: If you see demo codde it matches `FOO`, `FOO"`, '`FOO`, `xFOO` etc . Only thing it doesn't match is **`"FOO"`**

Comment: **Enhanced Demo:** http://ideone.com/kL3I3M

Comment: @anubhava: Yes, I was using debuggex, and it said that "FOO is not a match. I have tried it in Java, and it seems to do the trick.

Comment: I told you earlier not to reply on debuggex and see working code :)

Comment: @KendallFrey: In case of success an atomic group can be usefull too, since the regex engine doesn't record backtrack positions inside the group, and thus go faster.

Comment: @anubhava You don't need to capture a group. You don't need a group at all, in this case.

Comment: @KendallFrey: Agreed than `/(?<!")FOO|FOO(?!")/` would also work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern:

```
"FOO"(*SKIP)(?!)|FOO
```

(since debuggex doesn't have a full support of pcre, you can test it with http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ or with http://www.phpliveregex.com/ or http://regexp.zug.fr/)